# How to export jFrog Artifactory repositories through REST API or a jFrog CLI command?

Tags: rest, artifactory, jfrog-cli

Using the UI, I can export Artifactory repositories. I'll be able to do it as mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Import+and+Export).

But what if I want to do it through a Rest API call or a jFrog CLI command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JFrog has a CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory) that can be used for many kinds of command line, automated or maintenance tasks. This CLI integrates great with CI/CD and with on demand tasks like downloading a file or a full repository.

Another option is to use the [Artifactory REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveFolderorRepositoryArchive), which can be used to download a whole repository or folder from it. There are a zillion options for the REST API.

For system export, you need to use the [Export System](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ExportSystem) REST API call.

Comment: When I do it manually, I use this process to export the repositories.
1) choose all repository 2)providing the path to: /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/export (server path) 3) exclude metadata, and then I click on export button on Artifactory UI. and I have searched the JFrog  CLI commands, but I don't find any command to export the repository. Could you help me which command should I use in order to achieve above manual process?

Comment: Ah... so you mean to apply the system export option. In this case, you need to use the REST API for system export (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ExportSystem). I will add this to the answer.

Comment: I have installed docker Artifactory and when I am running this Rest API command to export the repository
** curl -u admin:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @/tmp/export-settings.json http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/export/system ** (Command end)

Export-settings.json file contains these two lines-       ** "exportPath" : "/tmp/",
                                                              "includeMetadata" : true, **
question: - I am getting the successful message from curl command, But when I am looking into the /tmp/ directory, nothing is there.

Comment: Are you looking a the /tmp where the artifactory server? You probably have it in the Docker container's /tmp, which is not mounted from your host.

Comment: When I am exporting the artifacts it's downloading the pom.sha256,pom.md5, pom.sha1 and jar.sha256, jar.md5, jar.sha1.  How to ignore these extra files, just want to download .jar and .pom. thats it. please suggest.

Comment: The export is for exporting *everything* in the repository. You can apply a filter after the export by simply finding and deleting all the *.sha256, *.md5 etc.